# how to declare a photo element in xsd containing a sequence of nested child element?

Tags: xml, xsd

> So I keep getting this error in the xsd file for my photos element it says "s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'catalog' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: element."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <!--
       New Perspectives on XML
       Tutorial 3
       Case Problem 1

       Catalog of photos from the Our Lady of Bergen Historical Society
       Author: Joshua Carpentier
       Date:   2/20/19

       Filename:         catalog.xsd
       Supporting Files: catalog.xml
    -->      
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:simpleType name="cidType " > 
    <xs:restriction base ="xs:ID"> 
    <xs:pattern value= "c\d{4}" /> 
    </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:simpleType > 

    <xs:simpleType name="srcType" > 
    <xs:restriction base ="xs:string"> 
    <xs:pattern value= "[a-zA-Z0-9]+.jpg" /> 
    </xs:restriction> 
    </xs:simpleType > 

    <xs:element name="catalog">`enter code here`
     <xs:element name="photo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">


    <xs:complexType > 
     <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="name" type="string" />
     <xs:element ref="description" type="string" />
     <xs:element ref="date" type="string" />
     <xs:element ref="images" type="string" />
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 


    <xs:attribute ref="cid" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="metadata" />
    <xs:attribute ref="donatedBy" use="optional" type="string" />
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="img" use="required" src=".jpg" />
    <xs:element ref="metadata" type="string" />
    <xs:element ref="cid"  type="cidType" />
    <xs:element ref="src"  type="srcType" />


</xs:schema>



**im trying to achieve this
```

Declare the photo element containing the following sequence of nested child elements—name,
description, date, and images. Set the following properties for the nested elements:
a. All of the child elements should contain string data. The name element should also support
the metadata attribute.
b. The cid attribute is required. The donatedBy attribute is optional.

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!--
   New Perspectives on XML
   Tutorial 3
   Case Problem 1

   Catalog of photos from the Our Lady of Bergen Historical Society
   Author: Joshua Carpentier
   Date:   2/20/19

   Filename:         catalog.xml
   Supporting Files: catalog.xsd
-->


    <catalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalog.xsd">

       <photo cid="c1748" donatedBy="John Borelli">
          <name metadata="tunis cooper property museum">Tunis R. Cooper property</name>
          <description>
          <![CDATA[ 
             This photo was taken by John Borelli's great-grandfather. It is believed to have been taken around 1830.
             David Demarest originally purchased the site of the chair factory in 1663. This site was under the ownership of the Demarest family until 1758.  The property is listed in the National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
          ]]>
          </description>
          <date>circa 1830</date>
          <images>
             <img src="1748a.jpg" />
             <img src="1748b.jpg" />
          </images>
       </photo>

       <photo cid="c1749" donatedBy="John Borelli">
          <name metadata="tunis cooper property museum">Tunis R. Cooper property</name>
          <description>
          <![CDATA[ 
             A more recent picture of the property taken by the Borelli family.  The property is listed in the 
             National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
          ]]>
          </description>
          <date>circa 1950</date>
          <images>
             <img src="1749a.jpg" />
          </images>
       </photo>

       <photo cid="c1411" donatedBy="Saint Johns Catholic Church">
          <name metadata="saint johns catholic church">Saint Johns Church</name>
          <description>
          <![CDATA[ 
             A more recent picture of the property taken by the Borelli family.  The property is listed in the 
             National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
          ]]>
          </description>      
          <date>1921</date>
       </photo>


       <photo cid="c2003" donatedBy="Linda Choo">
          <name metadata="bergenfield elementary school">Bergenfield School</name>
          <description>
          <![CDATA[ 
             The No. 5 Public School, a.k.a. Bergenfield School
          ]]>
          </description>
          <date>circa 1920</date>
          <images>
             <img src="2003a.jpg" />
             <img src="2003b.jpg" />
          </images>
       </photo>

       <photo cid="c2078" donatedBy="Maria Giodelli">
          <name metadata="coopers pond water">Coopers Pond</name>
          <description>
          <![CDATA[ 
             A favorite spot where we used to go hang out as kids.  The picture shows my brothers Robert and Michael.
          ]]>
          </description>
          <date>May 4, 1941</date>
          <images>
             <img src="2078a.jpg" />
          </images>
       </photo>

       <photo cid="c2079" donatedBy="Linda Uffington">
          <name metadata="watch timekeeping pocket railway">Pocket Watch</name>
          <description>
          <![CDATA[ 
             A more recent picture of the property taken by the Borelli family.  The property is listed in the 
             National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
          ]]>
          </description>
          <date>circa 1870</date>
          <images>
             <img src="2079a.jpg" />
             <img src="2079b.jpg" />
          </images>
       </photo>

       <photo cid="c3233">
          <name metadata="hotel">Bergenfield Hotel</name>
          <description>
          <![CDATA[ 
             The Knollfield Hotel was known as the Bergenfield Hotel.  The property is listed in the 
             National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
          ]]>
          </description>
          <date>circa 1920</date>
       </photo>

       <photo cid="c3433">
          <name metadata="sweeney coal fuel">Sweeney Coal</name>
          <description>
          <![CDATA[ 
             Sweeney Fuel Company located near New Bridge Road and railroad tracks.
          ]]>
          </description>
          <date>1920</date>
          <images>
             <img src="3433a.jpg" />
             <img src="3433b.jpg" />
             <img src="3433c.jpg" />
          </images>
       </photo>

</catalog>
```

Comment: Please check that you have entered your XSD and XML correctly. The text "enter code here" within backticks looks very out of place, and there are elements that aren't closed. It's clearly not a valid schema, but the errors don't relate clearly to the error message you are reporting, so I suspect we're seeing spurious errors in addition to the real ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `xs:element` element cannot have another `xs:element` element as a child. Typically `xs:element` has `xs:complexType` as a child, which itself has `xs:sequence` as a child, which in turn has `xs:element` as a child.

Answer (score 0):

You XSD file is invalid. It is not *well-formed*. To correct it, complete the element with a closing tag. So replace

```
<xs:element name="catalog">`enter code here`
  <xs:element name="photo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  ...
</xs:element>
```

with

```
<xs:element name="catalog">
    <xs:element name="photo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="name" type="string"/>
          <xs:element ref="description" type="string"/>
          <xs:element ref="date" type="string"/>
          <xs:element ref="images" type="string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute ref="cid" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute ref="metadata"/>
      <xs:attribute ref="donatedBy" use="optional" type="string"/>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="img" use="required" src=".jpg"/>
    <xs:element ref="metadata" type="string"/>
    <xs:element ref="cid" type="cidType"/>
    <xs:element ref="src" type="srcType"/>
</xs:element>
```

Now your XSD will validate your XML.

Comment: That's still not well-formed - the element name="photo" isn't closed. And even if it were well-formed, it wouldn't be a valid schema document; xs:element can't have xs:element as a child,

Comment: Sorry, the combination of bad indentation in the original question and bad indentation in your answer had me confused. I think you've made it well-formed  (though badly indented) XML, but you certainly haven't made it into a valid schema.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I was confused, too. I now changed my answer, but I'm still unsure if this is correct. I did use `xmlstarlet` to validate the XSD and it did validate the XML as _valid_.

Comment: I still wonder why the first version was considered to be "valid" by `xmlstarlet`.